# Computing Stiefel Whitney classes

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, characteristic-classes

I am computing the cohomology of $BO(2) \times B0(3)$ and I would like to identify the Stiefiel Whitney classes of this space.

For instance, I know $H^*(BO(2);\mathbb{Z}/2)\cong \mathbb{Z}/2[w_1,w_2]$ , $H^*(BO(3);\mathbb{Z}/2)\cong \mathbb{Z}/2[w_1',w_2',w_3']$ and the cross product $H^*(BO(2);\mathbb{Z}/2) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}/2} H^*(BO(3);\mathbb{Z}/2) \cong H^*(BO(2) \times BO(3);\mathbb{Z}/2)$. Then if $p_1:BO(2) \times B0(3) \to BO(2)$ and $p_2:BO(2) \times B0(3) \to BO(3)$ are the projections onto the first and second factors respectively, $\alpha_i=p_1^*(w_i)$, and $b_j=p_2^*(w_j')$. I have $H^1(BO(2) \times BO(3);\mathbb{Z}/2)=\langle \alpha_1, \beta_1\rangle$, but what should be the first Stiefel Whitney class in terms of $\alpha_1$ and $\beta_1$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $BO(2) \times BO(3)$ is not a manifold, so it doesn't have Stiefel-Whitney classes.

Comment: I have a 2-fold covering $\widetilde{B} \to BO(2) \times BO(3)$. So according to Milnor-Stasheff (page 145) I can construct a line bundle $\xi$ over $ BO(2) \times B0(3)$ and thus I can think $w_1 = w_1(\xi)$ as $w_1$ for $ BO(2) \times BO(3)$ is this not correct? Thanks!

Comment: Of course you can talk about the Stiefel-Whitney classes of a vector bundle on any space, but when people say "Stiefel-Whitney classes of a space" they mean the Stiefel-Whitney classes of the tangent bundle of a smooth manifold.

Comment: I really sorry for my mistake, so what I would like to ask is how can I identify the first class of Stiefel Whitney of my 2-fold covering $\widetilde{B} \to BO(2) \times BO(3)$?...Sorry again, thanks!

Comment: Of course it depends on which $2$-fold covering you mean. There are $3$, and each one gives the $3$ possible nontrivial $w_1$.